# Не работает цикл PHP. DLE

Tags: php

Написал модуль для админки DLE своими корявыми ручками)
На последнем этапе возникла проблема с циклом. Он не хочет работать при вставке кода. В примере ниже отмечен комментариями начало и конец куска кода, с которым циклне работает и без которого работает.

```
$db->query("SELECT * FROM ".USERPREFIX."_orders");

while($row = $db->get_row()) {

            /* НАЧАЛО ЕРУНДЫ */
            $user_id = $row['user_id'];
    $order_id = $row['order_id'];

    $db->query("SELECT name FROM ".USERPREFIX."_users WHERE user_id = '$user_id'");
    $b = $db->get_row();

    $db->query("SELECT * FROM ".USERPREFIX."_order WHERE id = '$order_id'");
    $c = $db->get_row();
            /* КОНЕЦ */

            echo '<tr>
    <td>'.$b['name'].'</td>
    <td>'.$c['title'].'</td>
    <td>'.$c['price_usd'].'</td>
    <td>'.$c['price_eur'].'</td>
    <td>'.$c['price_rub'].'</td>
    <td><a href="'.$module.'&end='.$row['id'].'">'.($row['is_end'] == 0 ? 'Нет': 'Да').'</a></td>
    <td><a href="'.$module.'&delete='.$row['id'].'"><img src="'.$config['http_home_url'].'engine/skins/images/delete.png" alt="Удалить" /></a></td>
    </tr>';
}
```

Как бы с этим кодом все хорошо, но цикл выводит только одну строчку из БД. Без него выводит столько, сколько там есть, но вот $b, $c и т.п. не работают. Помогите пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

На первый взгляд проблема в следующем: вызывая запросы внутри цикла, Вы затираете результат первого запроса (`$db->query("SELECT * FROM ".USERPREFIX."_orders")`). Поэтому вам сначала надо сохранить результат первого запроса в массив, и потом по нему пройтись, выполнив Ваш код.

Comment: А если не сложно можно представить кусок таблицы, и то что вы хотите из нее получить и представить? Возможно найти другой путь решения вез множественных циклов?

Comment: В итоге мы должны получить имя юзера, заказавшего товар, имя товара и его цену (грубо говоря).

orders - список заказов, там указаны id юзера и id товара.
По этим id мы и смотрим имя пользователя в users и имя товара с ценой в order

Comment: можно схемы таблиц с отношениями?

Comment: Реляционная СУБД. Понятие реляционный (англ. relation — отношение).
Грубо говоря связь таблиц через определенные поля. Извените, но такие вещи нада знать)

Comment: в общем колонки orders: id(A_I) user_id(id пользователя), order_id(id товара). Ну а остальные расписывать не буду. В запросах "плохого куска" расписано

Comment: а вот USERPREFIX от чего зависит?

Comment: ни от чего. Это простой префикс для таблиц в БД. Таблички называются dle_tablename